# Ruby: stuck on a koan

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm working on RubyKoans.com and got stuck in `about_symbols.rb` with this koan.

This is the test: I assume I'm supposed to put something in the brackets after `assert_raise()` but I have no idea:

```
def test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated
    # Exceptions will be pondered further father down the path
    assert_raise(___) do
      :cats + :dogs
    end
  end
```

This is the hint in the terminal:

```
The answers you seek...
  [FillMeInError] exception expected, not  Class: <NoMethodError>  Message: <"undefined method `+' for :cats:Symbol">  ---Backtrace---  /Users/mm/Sites/koans/about_symbols.rb:89:in `block in test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated'  ---------------
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer. Supposed to put the error in the brackets.

```
  def test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated
    # Exceptions will be pondered further father down the path
    assert_raise(NoMethodError) do
      :cats + :dogs
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

When you get stuck on a koan, just try it in an irb. It can help you know what to fill.

```
$ irb
>> :symbol + :another_symbol
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for :symbol:Symbol
from (irb):2
```